# Rails 3 App with tolk raises exception on rake tolk:setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I created a fresh rails-3.2.2 app. Added

```
gem "tolk", :git => "http://github.com/dhh/tolk.git", :branch => "rails3" # https://github.com/dhh/tolk/commit/088938ed4d117ac8820d38ddcd9004da62c670ce
```

to my Gemfile.

Then I tried:

```
`--> bundle exec rake --trace tolk:setup
** Invoke tolk:setup (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object
/Users/at/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@splink/bundler/gems/tolk-088938ed4d11/config/environments/development.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/at/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@splink/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/Users/at/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@splink/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/Users/at/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@splink/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/Users/at/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@splink/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/Users/at/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@splink/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:571:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/Users/at/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@splink/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/Users/at/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@splink/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/Users/at/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@splink/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/Users/at/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@splink/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
/Users/at/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@splink/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/Users/at/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@splink/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
/Users/at/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@splink/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/Users/at/dev/dosb/tolk_test/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
```

So the most pressing question is how I get this to work? 
The problem are the 'config.... = ...' lines in the development.rb of the top line of the backtrace.

Other interesting questions are: Through which level of rails wizardry is this supposed to work (where's config supposed to come from?)

Is the gem really overriding the config of my app (caching and mailer settings)? And am I the only one finding this questionable?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without seeing your code, but I suspect it is that in rails3 your environment.rb needs to be wrapped in:

Core::Application.configure do

config.stuff.goes.here()

end

This was not required in rails2, which may be the source of the problem.

It looks like tolk may not be ready for rails3.

It is not that the tolk gem is overriding your config settings, but when it tries to perform it's own config, it fails due to the outdated config format.

Comment: I took a freshly initialized rails app, so my environment.rb should be fine. Also, it does work until I put the tolk dep into my Gemfile. The branch name 'rails3' made me suspect that it would work with rails 3